# What is abc<xyz> in typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, feathersjs

I am new to ts

for my this code

```
import service from "feathers-mongoose";

app.use("/orders", service({
    CustomerModel
}));
```

Typescript is throwing following error

> Argument of type '{ CustomerModel: Model<Document, {}>; }' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'Partial'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'CustomerModel'
> does not exist in type 'Partial'.

Where my customer model looks like this

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const customerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Model = mongoose.model("customers", customerSchema);

export default Model;
```

Can someone explain to me what does `Partial< MongooseServiceOptions>`

Also, I know this could be one of the questions which could've already been asked on stackoverflow but I google searched the exact same phrase and I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Not a full answer, but what you are looking for is called [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with `feathers-mongoose`, so I can't help you debug your specific problem, but I might be able to provide some insight into the `Partial` type.

#### Generics

As mentioned by one of the comments, `Partial` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). A useful way to think of generics is like a **type function**. Similar to how functions are just things that take an *input* and produce an *output*, generics allow us to supply a *type* as input and receive a *type* as an output.

Let's use the `Array` generic as an example. By itself, `Array` is not a type. After all, we'd have to know what kind of array it is -- is it a string array, or number array, or some other kind of array?

Now, remember how I said a generic is like a **type function**? Like how normal functions take variables as input, generics take **type variables** as input. By supplying a type variable to `Array`, we can specify what kind of array we want. For instance, we can pass `string` as a type variable to `Array` with the syntax `Array<string>` (note that this is remarkably similar to normal function syntax; the only difference is that we use angle brackets instead of parentheses). Here's an example:

```js
const stringArray: Array<string> = ['a', 'bunch', 'of', 'strings']
const numberArray: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As you can see, the generic `Array` allows us to define essentially *infinite* types. We could define things like `Array<boolean>`, `Array<Person>`, `Array<Dog>`, etc. In fact, the syntax `type[]` is functionally equivalent to `Array<type>`.

#### Partial

Now, let's return to `Partial`. `Partial` is a special generic defined by TypeScript that makes all fields of an interface optional. For instance, if we had the interface:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
  favoriteColor: string
}
```

`Partial<Person>` would be equivalent to this interface:

```js
interface MaybeAPerson {
  name?: string
  age?: number
  favoriteColor?: string
}
```

As you can see, generics again allow us to define new and useful types without having to write a bunch of repetitive code.

#### How is Partial implemented?

This is a bit out of the scope of the question, but I thought it might be useful to include how `Partial` is implemented because it can be done in native TypeScript. Here's the implementation that's given in the [documentation](https://www.staging-typescript.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```js
type Partial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P]
}
```

Let's break this down:

1. `<T>` (next to `Partial`) signifies that `Partial` is a generic with a single type variable `T`.
2. `keyof T` lists out the keys of the type variable `T` as a union type. For example, if `T` were the `Person` type I defined above, `keyof T` would give us the type `'name' | 'age' | 'favoriteColor'`.
3. `[P in keyof T]` maps the keys of `T` to the keys of `Partial<T>`. If we were to define `Partial<Person>`, `[P in keyof T]` would set its keys to `name`, `age`, and `favoriteColor`.
4. `T[P]` sets the value of each key to the original type.
5. The `?` sets all the keys to optional.

If that didn't make sense, don't worry. In simpler terms, what all this fancy syntax is doing is copying over the type variable `T` into `Partial<T>` but making all the fields optional.